# Is it possible to move the top activities bar of gnome shell to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, panel, activities-overview

I have set up a normal user account in my computer as a guest account, which lots of my friends use.

I love the gnome shell, and I set it as the desktop environment. The problem users of my computer usually encounter, even when "Activities" is shown at the upper left of the screen, is that they keep looking (and moving the mouse cursor) to the LOWER left of the screen. (Is this Windows' fault?) Well, it is because that's what they are familiar with.

I know of other DE's that has the Windows lower left Apps-button orientation. But I still love gnome shell. So, is the question above. Thank you. (And I think it would still be quite useful even if the bottom bar remains just there. I'm on 12.04, so that could mean, lower left hot corner = Activities/Windows, lower right hot corner = bottom bar. Not bad.)

PS. I've tried [Flippery Bottom Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/), and it doesn't really do what I exactly wanted.

Comment: You could possibly use something like Cairo Dock which, depending how you set it up can display a 'Start' type menu which may help.

Comment: You may want to consider Cinnamon...http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-cinnamon-in-ubuntu-1304-raring.html

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I actually have just recently placed Cairo Dock, which makes it very easy for them for the common apps. Although it lacks "type-to-search" feature, I've nonetheless placed the Apps Menu there. Cinnamon is OK, but honestly, one of the nicest things I love about GS is the Overwiew. But if it is really too difficult to place the bar to the bottom, well, I guess I'll just leave it as it is: with Cairo Dock (and maybe a wallpaper with a conspicuous arrow pointing upper left: "Click Here"). :)